# How to get Zurb Foundation 3 working on Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, zurb-foundation

Zurb Foundation 3 says is compatible with IE8. This is the reason I'm using F3.

I have problems getting to work F3 on IE8. 
I tried the official http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/grid.php which seems to have the same problems on IE8 which I found on my own site.

More specifically:

1. Navigation is messed up (The sticky menu is comming like an unstyled
   vertical ul/li)
2. Orbit Javascript slider component doesn't work
3. Initially accordition looks fine visually. However when clicked it
   doen't work as expected
4. Reveal modals don't work

The same problems are happening on both my site and the official F3 docs page - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/3.2.5/grid.php

What could be the problem?

I suspect it might be something related with including things like html5shiv, etc. However I try to stick as much as possible with how the official F3 is showing. In the demo index.html of Foundation 3 following things are included:

```
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->

<!-- Included CSS Files (Compressed) -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/foundation.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/app.css">

<script src="javascripts/modernizr.foundation.js"></script>

<!-- Included JS Files (Compressed) -->
<script src="javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/foundation.min.js"></script>

<!-- Initialize JS Plugins -->
<script src="javascripts/app.js"></script>

<script>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#featured").orbit();
    });
</script>
```

Do I need to include something else? html5shiv would be enough or I need other things also?

Answer (score 0):

Adding html5shiv.html solved most of the issues.

The only one remaining is that images (transparent PNGs) remain and accumulate on screen (one on top of the other) while the Orbit slider is running.